# Search with AND operator in MongoDB using $text query operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, mongodb-indexes

I already have text index in MongoDB.

Simple search:

```
db.news.find({ $text: { $search: "covid" } })
```

I get all the articles containing *covid* in the text.

Now I want to get all the articles that contain both *covid* **and** *vaccination*.

This query for example...

```
db.news.find({ $text: { $search: "\"covid vaccination\"" } })
```

...will only find articles that contain *"covid vaccination"* side by side, in that order.
In other words, article structured like this: *"Vaccination against covid..."* will not be found.

I want to find all articles where *covid* and *vaccination* are included in the article, regardless of each word position, using the text index. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I re-checked MongoDB documentation and didn't find the way how to do it. May be this will help:

```
db.news.find({$text: {$search: "covid vaccination"}}).sort({score: {$meta: "textScore"}})
```

It wouldn't get the required result, but, at least, the result will sorted by score. The records which contains the both "covid" and "vaccination" should be at the top

Comment: It functions like there is an OR operator between the words. I get all the covid articles and all the vaccination articles.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I updated my comment to, at least, try to help you to find a solution

Comment: One step closer to the end goal. Thank you :)